# can anyone explain me this assert condition?

Tags: function, token, blockchain, solidity, pragma

i would like to understand this assert condition in function send token.....i think the first assert for before adding tokenbalance is always gather then the up coming token but I don't sure about it....?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.11;
contract EventExample {

 mapping(address => uint) public tokenBalance;

 event TokensSent(address _from, address _to, uint _amount);

 constructor() public {
 tokenBalance[msg.sender] = 100;
 }

 function sendToken(address _to, uint _amount) public returns(bool) {
 require(tokenBalance[msg.sender] >= _amount, "Not enough tokens");
 assert(tokenBalance[_to] + _amount >= tokenBalance[_to]);
 assert(tokenBalance[msg.sender] - _amount <= tokenBalance[msg.sender])
;
 tokenBalance[msg.sender] -= _amount;
 tokenBalance[_to] += _amount;

 emit TokensSent(msg.sender, _to, _amount);

 return true;
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two `assert` conditions provide a way to prevent integer overflow and underflow.

The max value of `uint256` is 2^256-1, which is approx. 10^77. If you want to add two numbers that would result in a value larger that the max value, it would overflow the integer.

---

Example with smaller values so it's easier to imagine:

Largest value of `uint8` is 255. So if you have a value 250 and you want to add 10, it overflows the max value, and becomes 4 (because 255  + 1 equals 0 in case of `uint8`).

The same goes the other way around. You have a value 5 and want to subtract 10. Since it's an unsigned integer, there's no negative numbers, and it underflows and becomes 251 (because 5 - 5 is 0, and then the remaining 5 is subtracted from the "max value + 1").

---

You can find more info about the integer overflow/underflow vulnerability in the SWC registry: https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-101

Comment: okay i understand the overflow and underflow but I want know that what the condition apply in assert like in require that the owner account token is always gather then the amount if it's false then it will give the error what condition actually says I just want to know it?what the meaning of that condition?

Comment: `assert(tokenBalance[_to] + _amount >= tokenBalance[_to]);` This checks whether the `tokenBalance[_to]` value becomes **lower** (i.e. overflows) when you **add** the `_amount`. If it does overflow (the value is not larger or equal), the `assert()` condition results in `false`, so it throws an exception.

Comment: and what about second assert condition?

Comment: It's pretty much the same. `assert(tokenBalance[msg.sender] - _amount <= tokenBalance[msg.sender])` checks whether the `tokenBalance[msg.sender]` becomes **higher** (i.e. underflows) when you **subtract** the `_amount`. If it does underflow (the value is not smaller or equal), the `assert()` condition results in `false`, so it throws an exception.